# Разрешение на доступ к файловой системе

Tags: android, android-permissions

дорогие друзья! Задача - написать приложение под Android (я использую язык Java), при открытии которого на экран выводится изображение с фронтальной камеры и сохраняется каждые 500мс в папку. Проблема: не могу получить доступ к файловой системе. При этом в Manifest прописал следующие разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

в MainActivity прописал следующий код:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Нет разрешения на запись файлов в ФС", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
    }
```

в телефоне в настройках приложения в списке возможных разрешений есть доступ к камере, но нет доступа к файловой системе. При этом в коде самого приложения, когда я пытаюсь вызвать методы, подразумевающие доступ к файловой системе, приложение не вылетает.

Toast срабатывает, но диалоговое окно с запросом разрешения не появляется.

Версия андроид - 13.

Comment: Это разрешение запросить нельзя, можно лишь отправить юзера в настройки, где он сможет его включить. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access

Comment: но проблема в том, что в настройках разрешение на доступ к файловой системе не отображается в списке возможных разрешений

Comment: Возможно для Андроид 13 надо использовать разрешение android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES

Comment: "сохраняется каждые 500мс в папку" -- что за папка? есть места, где вообще никакие разрешения не нужны https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: Разрешение [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) устарело. Если у вас Target SDK равен 30 или выше, то задавать это разрешение не имеет смысла, оно будет проигнорировано. Используйте [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage), если вам нужно сохранять данные в публичные директории. Либо сохраняйте во внутреннее хранилище [`filesDir`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) или `cacheDir`, туда есть доступ всегда.